# Do Google Cloud Function Secrets Persist?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools, google-secret-manager

I'm trying to find the best way to store my AWS keys for a Google Cloud Function. They say not to store it in the code or in an environment variable, so I was looking into creating a "secret file" and mounting it at `/~/.aws/credentials` - However this idea only works if the secret file persists across function deploys.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/secrets) doesn't say anything about it, but I've found in the past environment variables are reset each deploy, and the secrets are modified on the same page.

So my question is - Between deploys, do the assigned/mounted secrets persist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Secret Manager is configured independently from Cloud Functions.  Your code deployed as Functions just reach into the configurations in Secret Manager.  A function deployment does not change anything in Secret Manager.